# too many redirects error on cpanel

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, hosting, cpanel

I am trying to host a javascript-PHP application on cPanel. I get `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error when I redirect from my home page `/index.php` to new page under different directory i.e., `/pathname/index.php`

My `.htaccess` file contains this:
`

```
# WP REWRITE LOOP START

RewriteEngine on

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  %2/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

`
And the .js file has

```
 window.location.href ="pathname/index.php";
```

upon successful login.

I looked up how to rewrite URL but resulted in an unsuccessful attempt. Please suggest me what should I be writing in `.htaccess` file?

I don't have this problem on localhost.

Comment: You need to post your code here , .htaccess as well as your php code as well. otherwise it's difficult to answer.

Comment: Thanks. Added the code. Please let me know if anything else is needed.